# conversion de acces a mysql

Tags: mysql

cordial saludo. 
necesito convertir una consulta que tengo en acces para pasarla a mysql e logrado la conversión de la mayoría de la consulta pero la parte de la operación matemática no me a dejado y me sale error...
la consulta es esta..

**Consulta acces**

```
SELECT Inventario.Referencia, Inventario.Nombre, Inventario.Existencias, transito.cantidad AS Transitos, ConsumoTotales.Consumos, 100 AS Futuro, IIf(IsNull([Consumos]),(0),Round(([Consumos]/10)*3)) AS Minimo, IIf([Minimo]>[Existencias],1) AS Alerta, IIf([Alerta]=1,Nz([Consumos],0)+[Minimo]-[Existencias]-Nz([Transitos],0),0) AS Pedido
FROM (Inventario LEFT JOIN transito ON Inventario.Referencia = transito.referencia) LEFT JOIN ConsumoTotales ON Inventario.Referencia = ConsumoTotales.REFERENCIA;
```

**consulta mysql**

```
SELECT inventario.referencia, inventario.nombre, inventario.existencia, transitos.cantidad AS transitos, total_consumo.Consumos, 100 AS Futuro, If(IsNull(Consumos),0,Round((Consumos/10)*3)) AS Minimo, If('Minimo'>'Existencias',1,0) AS Alerta  If( Alerta=1, Ifnull(cantidad,0)+ Minimo - Existencias - Ifnull(transitos,0) AS Pedido
FROM inventario LEFT JOIN transitos ON inventario.referencia = transitos.referencia LEFT JOIN total_consumo ON inventario.referencia = total_consumo.REFERENCIA;
```

agradezco si me pueden ayudar no tengo mucha practica en esto.

Comment: Hola Sebastian, bienvenido a [es.so]. en la mysql no te falta una coma despues de  `AS Alerta`? Qué errores te da?  Mira [ask] y [mcve] para mejorar tu pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: Creo que tambien falta un parentesis de cierre para: If( Alerta=1

Comment: gracias el error que me sale que sale es: 
SELECT inventario.referencia, inventario.nombre, inventario.existencia, transitos.cantidad AS transitos, total_consumo.Consumos, 100 AS Futuro, If(IsNull(Consumos),0,Round((Consumos/10)*3)) AS Minimo, If('Minimo'>'Existencias',1,0) AS Alerta,  If( Alerta=1, Ifnull(cantidad,0)+ Minimo - Existencias - Ifnull(transitos,0)) AS Pedido FROM inventario LEFT JOIN transitos ON inventario.referencia = transitos.referencia LEFT JOIN total_consumo ON inventario.referencia = total_consumo.REFERENCIA; es que hay algo mal antes de ') As pedido

Comment: aclaro que 
Se tienen 4 tablas invantario, transitos, conusmos, y pedidos futuros de la tabla consumo sale una vista que se llama total_consumo 
que lo que hace es de cada referencia generar un total por referencia para el calculo de los pedidos.
solo se genera pedido cuando minimo>existencia y por ese motivo tenemos colomna de alerta para que cuando se cumpla esta condicion 
muestre un 1 y luego generar una notificacion.

Comment: usa el boton [edit]. pon toda la informacion en la pregunta, en los comentarios no se entiende. y no estas aclarando que error te sale